# Make string with special character to array variable php

Tags: php, arrays, variables

There's

```
trainingData = [[3, 1],[6, 1]]
```

How to make `trainingData` an array variable?

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking. Could you add more detail please

Comment: What exactly you are trying to do ?

Comment: can u please provide more details.. what do u mean by `trainingData` and what's your question exactly ????

Answer (score 0):

This way you can achieve.

```
<?php
    $trainingData = '[[3, 1],[6, 1]]';
    $array = json_decode($trainingData);

    //Array variable
    print_r($array);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you come from Python (or any other language that uses that kind of array defining), then you want to know how to define an array in PHP. Then there are a lot of different ways to do this but I will give you 2 fast examples:

Option 1:

```
<?php

$trainingData = array(
  array(3,1), 
  array(6,1)
);

var_dump($trainingData);
```

Option 2 (this one mostly used when using loops to append to arrays):

```
<?php

$trainingData = array();
$trainingData[] = array(3,1);
$trainingData[] = array(6,1);

var_dump($trainingData);
```

More information and examples you can find at [php docs about Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)